# Populating Select2 with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am trying to populate a selec2 field on open with AJAX in Drupal 8. In my hook_form_alter, I have added the following code:

```
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="form-ajax-wrapper">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  $form['field_author']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'myPopulate',
    'wrapper' => 'form-ajax-wrapper',
    'event' => 'select2:opening',
  ];
```

which correctly calls to the callback function when I try to open the drop-down list:

```
function reloadOptions(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
  $query->condition('type', 'author');
  $query->condition('status', 1);
  $nids = $query->execute();
  $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $options[$node->id()] = FieldFilteredMarkup::create($node->getTitle());
  }

  $form['field_author']['widget']['#options'] = $options;

  return $form;
}
```

The query is ok, and the way in which the options are loaded also seems ok. However, when I click on the selec2 field to open it, the ajax throbber is shown but the drop-down list does not open.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
A capture of the behaviour of the selector2. As you can see, the drop-down list is not displayed after you click. However, if the ajax call is removed, it works correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following post, a working solution has been provided: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2020-10-20/populating-select2-with-ajax

@No Sssweat also provided an alternative solution, where an update button was hidden in the form and was automatically activated with JS when a new item was added.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax callback is pointing to the wrong function, should be:

```
callback' => 'reloadOptions',
```

It's better to make it return just the field rather than the entire form

```
$form['field_author']['#prefix'] = '<div id="author-ajax-wrapper">';
$form['field_author']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

$form['field_author']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'reloadOptions',
  'wrapper' => 'author-ajax-wrapper',
  'event' => 'select2:opening',
];
```

Adjust the reloadOptions fuction, so it returns just the specific field

```
return $form['field_author'];
```

Comment: Yes, the name of the callback is wrong. It was my mistake when I copied the code.

Regarding returning only the specific field, that makes the rest of the form disappears and shows only the select2. Likewise, it does not manage to display the drop-down list either.

Comment: `that makes the rest of the form disappears and shows only the select2` @GJW80 Did you add the prefix and suffix to the author field `$form['field_author']`, [like I show in my answer](https://i.imgur.com/18BWfbS.png) and removed the prefix & suffix from the `$form` like you have in [your question](https://i.imgur.com/qk19bwK.png)?

Comment: That's right, my bad. However, the drop-down list is not yet displayed.

Comment: @GJW80 it's working, the issue is that it keeps replacing it before the options show. You'll need to add `unset($form['field_author']['widget']['#ajax']);` to you callback so it replaces only once.

Comment: Also, user might have to click twice, so change your event to `ready` or  `load`.

Comment: If I use `ready` or `load`, ajax is not called in select2 opening. The unset in the callback appears not to have any effect, even if I click twice in the select.

Comment: What if you set it to empty? `$form['field_author']['widget']['#ajax'] = [];`

Comment: No, still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115374/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-gjw80).